# Can I use Permanova to test If my samples are independent?

Tags: repeated-measures, independence, permutation-test

I am trying to assess If fish structure and composition differs significantly between two beaches with different levels of habitat complexity. As I only have one replicate of each type of beach, I adjusted my design in Permanova to account for pseudoreplication.
However, reviewers of my work are asking me to test if my samples within each beach are independent. He suggested I use Permanova for this test 
How can I test for independence of samples?

Ps.: This reviewer argued that I can only use Permanova when my samples are independent (which I'm not sure is true by reading the manual). But I would like to know if independence is an assumption for the Partial Redundancy Analysis (RDA).